# Where should I ask a question about character voice lines　In different languages?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Looking to understand what Abel says during all his special moves in USF4, but I've searched online, and the only thing I can find are voice clips in japanese (but no subtitles) and english quotes.

For example, I've been trying to see what　Abel says when using Wheel Kick.  In the American voice line, he says "Justice!", but in Japanese, it sounds more like "go ragna", which has lead me nowhere when searching online.

I want to ask it here, but not sure, since this is a gaming site, but not necessarily for Japanese, or should I ask it over at Japanese.SE.

This is something I am generally curious about, understanding the voice lines.  For example, when doing a Marseilles Roll, Abel will shout "I saw that" in english, but in Japanese, will say "mieto", which roughly translates to that. Same for some his other moves.  For example, at the start of Abel's U2, he'll say "Here I come", but in Japanese, he'll say "ikuzo!" which roughly means the same thing.

Comment: I believe this is on topic here regardless of whether or not it is on topic on Japanese.SE

Comment: @badp I just wanted to ask this to play it safe, not sure if "translations" are welcome in this site

Comment: In terms of getting an answer, if you know the language it is in you might have better luck asking experts in that language.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on the main site?

Comment: @EnmosProje I was asking it in the context of, if I asked this question on the main site, would it get closed or downvoted to hell?

Comment: You might have some luck on this site, if you can provide a good reference for where the line is (and an audio clip would not go amiss either!), but for a proper translation, you might do better on the appropriate language site.  Especially for really specific quotes.  We might still TRY to answer it, but better language experts would be found on language-based SE sites.

Comment: @Zibbobz Yeah, I have a youtube video with the audio clip, going to be hard to nail down the exact time since the voice lines come by very fast.